# Is it possible to convert string values to numbers in LogQL?

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

I am following [documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/) and thanks to `| line_format` and `regexReplaceAll` I was able to fetch some substring from a line.

Let's say now I have those columns:

```
line
123
7
123
54
14
```

Having that I want to perform some transform operation, ex sum, or transform operation with grouping by and taking total.
It is not working as I am suspecting those values are not being numbers, but only strings.
Is it possible to convert it to numbers?

I was trying using `unwrap` but it didn't worked:

```
sum_over_time(
    {service="some"} 
    |="text expression"
    | json
    | line_format `{{ regexReplaceAll "text expression to remove from (\\d+)" .label_id "${1}" | trim }}`
    | unwrap label_id [1m]
)
```

it ends up with

> pipeline error: 'SampleExtractionErr' for series:

when I am filtering out errors, there is no results.

Comment: Did you find a way to convert the String to an Integer or did you modify the data source? @Rumid

Answer (score 1):

You can use `int` or `float64` methods [documented on the official docs](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/template_functions/#int) to convert String to Int/Float

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly I'm trying to use the LogQL analyzer trying to solve this problem.

**Data:**

```
id="ID1" userId=100
id="ID2" userId=101
id="ID3" userId=200
```

**Question**: we want to get all rows for `userId` that end with `00`.

**Answer according LogQL Analyzer**:

- [logfmt | userId=100](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/query/analyzer/?query=%7C%20logfmt%20%7C%20userId%3D100&line%5B%5D=id%3D%22ID1%22%20userId%3D100&line%5B%5D=id%3D%22ID2%22%20userId%3D101&line%5B%5D=id%3D%22ID3%22%20userId%3D200) -> Fetches a row by id
- [logfmt | userId="100"](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/query/analyzer/?query=%7C%20logfmt%20%7C%20userId%3D100&line%5B%5D=id%3D%22ID1%22%20userId%3D100&line%5B%5D=id%3D%22ID2%22%20userId%3D101&line%5B%5D=id%3D%22ID3%22%20userId%3D200) -> It works as well when double quoted
- [logfmt | userId=~"[0-9]*00"](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/query/analyzer/?query=%7C%20logfmt%20%7C%20userId%3D100&line%5B%5D=id%3D%22ID1%22%20userId%3D100&line%5B%5D=id%3D%22ID2%22%20userId%3D101&line%5B%5D=id%3D%22ID3%22%20userId%3D200) -> This regex does the trick

But my reality on the real server is different:

- `logfmt | userId=~"[0-9]*00"` -> throws `invalid schema field type of "long" for "userId" expected one of [string uuid ipv4 ipv6 array(string) array(boolean) array(long) array(double) array(timestamp) array(datetime)]`
- `logfmt | userId="100"` -> with double quotes nothing is returned (without the quote the row is properly returned)

To work around I did:

```
logfmt | line_format "userId={{.userId}}" | logfmt | userId=~"[0-9]*0"`
```

It honestly sucks, but it's the only way I found.

(I'm on Grafana v10.0.9, but I have no idea what version of Loki/LogQL I'm am using).